# Is there a way where terraform ignores ResourceNotFoundException and destroys the other resources

Tags: terraform

I am trying to use a terraform destroy job but get ResourceNotFoundException. This is because the resources is already deleted in the previous job. Is there a way where terraform can ignore that the resource is deleted and destroy rest of infrastructure.

Example :- Dynamo table was deleted in the previous job and in the next job I want to delete the policy and role attached to it.

`Error retrieving DynamoDB table: ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found: Table`

Answer (score 16):

Sounds like if the resource is gone, but Terraform thinks it still exists to delete, your best bet is simply to update the state file to match.

```
terraform state rm <your_dynamo_table_resource>
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html

Comment: to add to @rome_leader, you can look up the actual resource name with ```terraform state list```, and then pass it to ```terraform state rm``` command.